# Magento Checkout Terms and Conditions, where are they stored?

Tags: database, magento, model

Magento has the possibility to enable **Checkout Terms and Conditions** and so diplay some text and a checkbox in the checkout page.

The feature is actionable following these steps:   http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/checkout_agreement/index

Now I wonder :

1. the value of the check box is saved somewhere ?
2. it is possible to view it in the backend ?

In case 1 is true and 2 is false, how can I add a column in the order table in order to display it ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense because if you enable terms and conditions it is impossible to check out with checkbox unchecked.

Comment: It make sense because you would like to save this event for legal purpose

Comment: Have you followed the controller back (i.e. the action the form is posted to, to see where/if it is saved)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering where the "Terms and Conditions" are stored in the database; they are stored in the `checkout_agreement` table.

I don't think it saves whether or not specific customers agreed to them, since they are required to checkout (i.e. compulsory).

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: hey i have changed the checkout process in 4 steps i have put validation for terms and condition but on place order i get errror bcz agreement is not saved can you tell me how can i send the agreement value (which is true ) with place order button so process works fine?

Comment: Hi @Harris - I would suggest posting your own question. I don't think there is enough information in your comment for anyone to help you.

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for replying i found the answer dont know its wrong or right answer but it works.
here is the link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/372719/magetno-2-how-to-send-the-request-of-place-order-when-user-checked-on-the-check?noredirect=1#comment510471_372719

Answer (score -3):

Yes it can be reviewed from back-end as well can be modified as follows:-
Sales=>Terms and Condition